# Python - Iso error for a dictionary file encryption

Tags: python, dictionary

This program is supposed to open a specified file read it contents and use the dictionary to encrypt the file's contents to the second file. It also can open an encrypted file and display its decrypted contents on screen. We were given pieces of the code and told to make it work. I believe I have the program almost there but when I enter the file name I get a ISO Error this is for the Decryption as well as the Encryption. I don't understand why it can't find the file name. I do in fact have the file I am trying to pick in the same folder.

```
    CODE = {'A':')','a':'0','B':'(','b':'9','C':'*','c':'8',\
            'D':'&','d':'7','E':'^','e':'6','F':'%','f':'5',\
            'G':'$','g':'4','H':'#','h':'3','I':'@','i':'2',\
            'J':'!','j':'1','K':'Z','k':'z','L':'Y','l':'y',\
            'M':'X','m':'x','N':'W','n':'w','O':'V','o':'v',\
            'P':'U','p':'u','Q':'T','q':'t','U':'P','u':'p',\
            'V':'O','v':'o','W':'N','w':'n','X':'M','x':'m',\
            'Y':'L','y':'l','Z':'K','z':'k','!':'J','1':'j',\
            '@':'I','2':'i','#':'H','3':'h','$':'G','4':'g',\
            '%':'F','5':'f','^':'E','6':'e','&':'D','7':'d',\
            '*':'C','8':'c','(':'B','9':'b',')':'A','0':'a',\
            ':':',',',':':','?':'.','.':'?','<':'>','>':'<',\
            "'":'"','"':"'",'+':'-','-':'+','=':';',';':'=',\
            '{':'[','[':'{','}':']',']':'}'}
    # Constants for the menu choices
    ENCRYPT=1
    DECRYPT=2
    QUIT_CHOICE=9

    def main():
        choice = 0

        while choice != QUIT_CHOICE:
            # display the menu
            display_menu()
            #user choice
            choice = int(input('Enter your choice: '))
            # Perform action
            if choice == ENCRYPT:
                encrypt()
            elif choice == DECRYPT:
                decrypt()
            elif choice == QUIT_CHOICE:
                print('Exiting the program...')
            else:
                print('Error: invalid selection.')

    # Encryption
    def encrypt():

        #Obtain a string of converted text
        result = convert()

        #Open and write in output file
        output_name = input("Enter the name of the output file: ")
        output_file = open(output_name, 'w')
        output_file.write(result)
        output_file.close()

    # Decryption
    def decrypt():

        # obtain a string  of converted text
        result = convert()

        # write text to screen
        print(result)

    #The convert function aske the user for a file name, opens the file and converts its contents using the CODE above.
    def convert():
        input_name = input("Enter the name of the input file: ")
        input_file = open(input_name, 'r')

        result = ''
        text = input_file.read()

        #Convert all charactors but spaces.
        for ch in text:

            if ch.isspace():
                result = result + ch
            else:
                result = result + CODE[ch]

        return result

    def display_menu():
        print('        ')
        print('    Encryption/Decryption Program version 1.1')
        print('        ')
        print(' 1) Encrypt a file')
        print(' 2) Decrypt a file')
        print(' 9) Exit')

    main()
```

Comment: I assume you mean `IOError`? And what exactly is that - please post the full tracebacks you receive... that contains the info. necessary...

Comment: Best guess is you're trying entering the same input/output file name for both... so more info. on that would be useful...

Comment: Give me a few moments I closed and reran the program and I believe it is picking up the file now but, I am having another error. I will edit once I figure out where I am going from here.